# Washing machine housing is electrified

Tags: electrical

If I bring my non-contact voltage tester within about an inch of any part of my washing machine's metallic housing, it beeps.

If I touch the machine, the tester stops beeping, but I don't feel a shock.

I plugged another washing machine into the same outlet and experienced the same behavior, so the issue seems to be the outlet, not the machine.

I then connected the washer to a different outlet on a different circuit, and the issue goes away. The metallic housing never has voltage when connected to the second circuit.

What could be the problem within the original outlet or the circuit that would cause this behavior?

I don't have a device to test the original outlet for ground, but the ground wire appears to be connected properly inside the box.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but have two reactions: 1) you may be getting a false positive from the tester, but  2) you instead may have a deadly situation. Be careful!

Comment: Spend $5 or less on *"a device to test the original outlet for ground"* aka a 3-lamp tester (staying under $5 you can also get one that will externally test GFCI outlets) and this might become clearer.

Comment: Is this washer touching an electric dryer by any chance?  Specifically, one that has one of the old, obsolete, dangerous 3-prong NEMA 10 connectors?

Comment: @DanielGriscom The tester works fine on everything else. Could you please elaborate on what would cause the deadly situation? Could it be that the ground wire is hot, or that the ground is not attached? I know neither of those things is good but didn't think either was deadly in most cases.

Comment: Without more info, I couldn't tell you what might be wrong, nor state that you aren't in danger. I'd just like for you to be careful.

Comment: @Ecnerwal could a lack of ground connection be causing the issue? I know not having ground could make me get shocked, but would that also explain why the washer housing is electrified? I didn't think that simply having an ungrounded outlet would do that.

Comment: A 3-lamp tester will display a number of potential fault mechanisms. Perhaps ground is open. Perhaps ground and neutral are switched, perhaps neutral and hot are switched, - the tester will give an indication a lot less vague than a non-contact voltage tester's not very informative "here be there voltage." Not completely definitive in some cases, but certainly **more information** at a *relatively low price.*

Comment: If you have enough voltage on the frame to set off a volt-tick, but you have touched the frame and not received a shock(don't perform this test, you may have just been insulated the first time), it is likely a grounding problem.  That said, unless you were sure you were grounded the first time, you may have a direct frame energisation problem in addition to a broken ground.  The best thing to do would be to measure with a volt meter.  Volt ticks should *never* be 100% trusted.  Their function is intended to be quick and easy, to increase safety when used properly *in addition to* a good meter.